# How to add my app on share menu on iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need my app to be added on the list on the share menu like Evernote.

[image]
I have only managed to add in on the list by adding `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and it is added on the list with "Open in.." with it.
[image]
The problem is that I want to know how to implement it the same as Evernote because on the first screen shot I'm using Voice Memos app(default iOS) that doesn't include my app on it, but when I used another app downloaded from the store it shows my app with "Open In.." with it.

Comment: You should read about Share Extension:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to implement this functionality with [Using an iOS 8 share extension to upload a photo to IBM Bluemix](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ios-8-share-extension-photos-ibm-bluemix?lang=en) . Just disregard the IBM Bluemix implementation.